# How to change font size on Main Menu in wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress

I am a beginner in learning WordPress, and I tried to change the font for the top menu on my website, but I could not I added a code as it appears in the picture, but the font on the top menu has not changed. What can I do?

Website
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHdhc.png]

my code:

```
#mainnav ul il a{
     font-size: 40px;
     color: #807f7f;
}
```

Comment: `#mainnav ul il a` should be `#mainnav ul li a` note the ***li*** for list-item

Comment: I have change it to #mainnav ul li a  , but the font size not change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be the font size is over written by other plugins / code. so if we use important property in code, that might solve the issue.

```
#mainnav ul li a{
     font-size: 40px !important;
     color: #807f7f;
}
```

And if you wish to change the font size in smaller device, add media query to do so.

```
/* When the browser is above 425px */
@media screen and (max-width: 425px) {
  #mainnav ul li a {
    /* Apply font styles */
  }
}
/* When the browser is above 768px */
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #mainnav ul li a {
    /* Apply font styles */
  }
}
```